# Is there a way to conditional sort criteria in views

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to make a conditional sort criteria with views in D7?

I want to do the following stuff:

```
if node property = x
  use this sort criteria
else
  use this one
```

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this using [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php).

Excerpt from the page:

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters
>   and sorts to views which use PHP code. It also supports additional
>   accounts when the core PHP Filter module is enabled.

Comment: You could use this module but I think putting PHP into the database is poor form.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function HOOK_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_name' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
    $query->orderby = array(
      array(
        'field' => 'CASE WHEN node.property = x THEN node.y ELSE node.z END',
        'direction' => 'ASC',
      )
    );
  }
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2133879